# microsoft excel for mac - fill down without dragging or clicking

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Microsoft Excel for Mac version 16.57. My spreadsheet looks like:

```
COL1 COL2
123 A
    B
    C
124 A
    B
    C
125 A
    B
    C
```

Is there a way to fill in 123, 124, 125, etc. all the way down without dragging or clicking each row? I know you can click the bottom right but I would like to avoid doing that. I would like to get

```
COL1 COL2
123 A
123 B
123 C
124 A
124 B
124 C
125 A
125 B
125 C
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of an auto-fill, but you could create a new column and use a formula such as this:

```
=VLOOKUP(9999999,A$2:A2,1,TRUE)
```

If col1 is a number, then use a number bigger than your biggest number. I used 9999999 here. If col1 is a string, then use something like "zzzzz".

[image]